# Passing a function accepting fewer parameters - how to enforce the same number of parameters for a function passed

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript I can assign a function that has fewer parameters into a variable of a function type that has more variables (but not the other way round, see [Comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)). That's how JS is used in practice, e.g.

Array.map accepts a callback of: `(t: T, idx: number, arr: T[]) -> U`

but we often pass a function that requires fewer params: `[1,2,3,4,5].map(e => e * 2)`

What if I want to enforce that only functions of strictly the same number of parameters are accepted (otherwise TSC errors)?As this relates to TypeScript, it should be a compile-time error, not a runtime one.

Example:

A simple calculator that accepts functions like this:

```
type ArithmeticFn = (a: number, b: number) => number;
```

I create some functions that satisfy the requirements

```
const add: ArithmeticFn = (a, b) => a + b;
const sub: ArithmeticFn = (a, b) => a - b;
const mul: ArithmeticFn = (a, b) => a * b;
```

and one that doesn't:

```
const sth: ArithmeticFn = (a) => a ** 2;
```

Below object will accept functions that have 2 or less params accepted:

```
const Calculator = {
    perform(oper: ArithmeticFn, op1, op2) { 
        return oper(op1, op2);
    }
}
```

Thus, below function breaks my logic:

```
Calculator.perform((a) => a**2, 1, 2)
```

In other words, is there any other way to enforce that (so that above example throws an error)? I could hack it by replacing positional fn params with an option bag (`{a: number, b: number}`), but this gets too dirty and breaks functional approach.

Comment: Maybe currying? `a => b => ...`

Comment: There is no way to force this, but is there a reason for this check ? At runtime this should not cause problems, If the function can do it's job with just part of the arguments why not let it. If the caller find he need more, he will find the other parameters..evetualy

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, there is - it's called type-safety ;) basically, the whole idea is that the programmer wants to shift the responsibility onto the platform, which accepts the code only when it satisfies some rules. Here, although I understand the origins of the decision, it falls in conflict with my intentions.. PS _If the caller find he need more, he will find the other parameters..evetualy_- do you mean getting runtime errors? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry the last part of that sentence got away from me. I meant that if the caller really needed any of the parameters to do their job, they would eventually discover that the function can have more (at compile time). The point of type safety is to avoid runtime errors, there is no runtime error that will derive from this. It's only a issue of discoverability. Even if you could force the caller to specify the parameters you will not be able to make them use the parameters, so why force them to declare unused parameters (there is actually a switch to report unused parameters as errors)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Do you mean functions don't need an accurate type? Can we just be sloppy about their formal parameters? Is this a well-typed program in Typescript: `map = f => xs => xs.map(f); map(() => {}) ([1,2,3,4])`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Even better: `map(() => window.prompt()) ([1,2,3,4])`. A compiler should prevent ill-typed programs, not merely runtime errors.

Comment: @ftor The goal of the Typescript  type system is not to be sound, it is to be practical, and allow what is commonly allowed in Javascript. Passing a function that takes fewer parameters to a callback that supplies more is common in Javascript and it should be safe in most scenarios.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Usually programming languages prefer soundness over completeness because a false positive program is undesirable. However, since sound ~ imprectical, there's nothing really to say anymore.

Comment: Is your goal to throw a TSC error or to enforce the number of parameters?

Comment: @Roman why _or_? Actually both. My goal is to get a TSC error when number of function parameters passed is different then the accepted type, which in turn would make TS accept only the specified number of params (it'd _enforce_ exact number of params). I'm looking for a compile-time solution (if it exists), not a runtime one (no hacks, no currying, etc) since that's out of scope.

Comment: The example provided doesn't really show case a problem, but something like this playground could be an issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6ut3uv - not pertaining to "less arguments" specifically, but still a case of parameters that don't match

Answer (score -1):

Using functon.length should be able to solve your problem.